# Host ID's on Network not in succession of 'active' or established devices?

Tags: ip, ping, local-area-network, arp, host

*Disclaimer: I am new to networking.*

I ran a `arp -a` command on Terminal to establish what devices are currently active on the network. I was returned a number of devices with Host ID's that were not in succession. For example, I had 1, 18, 19, 24, 40 etc.

I used `ping` on random host ID's that I cannot see on the arp list, for example 16, 35 and received a `request timeout`. I'm assuming that these devices are no longer on the network or being used on the network.

My question is: why does the network reserve a particular host ID even though it is no longer active on the network? In theory, shouldn't my arp list just be 1, 2, 3 and so on?